# How do i get unique value from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a=array("a"=>"Cat","b"=>"Dog","c"=>"Cat");
```

From the above array i need the value Dog alone. how can i get the unique value from an array?. is there any functions in php?...

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = array("a"=>"Cat","b"=>"Dog","c"=>"Cat");
$counted = array_count_values($a);
$result = array();
foreach($counted as $key => $value) {
  if($value === 1) {
    $result[] = $key;
  }
}
//$result is now an array of only the unique values of $a
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at:

http://php.net/function.array-unique

and maybe:

http://php.net/function.array-count-values

Answer (score 1):

```
function getArrayItemByValue($search, $array) {
    // without any validation and cheking, plain and simple
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($search === $value) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

then try using it:

```
echo $a[getArrayitembyValue('Dog', $a)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$a = array("a"=>"Cat","b"=>"Dog","c"=>"Cat");
$aFlip = array_flip($a);
$unique = array();

foreach ( array_count_values( $a ) as $key => $count ) {
    if ( $count > 1 ) continue;
    // $unique[ array_search($key) ] = $key;
    $unique[ $aFlip[$key] ] = $key;
}
```

Comment: +1 because this is nice if keys should be preserved. The runtime complexity is however terrible when using array_search here since it goes from O(n) to O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Use following function seems to be working & handy.

```
<?php 
$array1 = array('foo', 'bar', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy', 'xyzzy'); 

$dup = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array1, array_unique($array1))); 

$result = array_diff($array1, $dup);

print_r($result);
?>
```

You can see its working here - http://codepad.org/Uu21y6jf

Answer (score -1):

```
$a=array("a"=>"Cat","b"=>"Dog","c"=>"Cat");
$result = array_unique(a);
print_r($result);
```

try this one...