# How to get unique array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'v an array like this:

```
Array([0] => 1,[1] => 2,[2] => 3,[3] => 3,[4] => 4,[5] => 5,[6] => 5,[7] => 6,[8] => 6,[9] => 6,[10] => 7,[11] => 8,[12] => 8,[13] => 8,[14] => 8,[15] => 9,[16] => 9,[17] => 9,[18] => 9,[19] => 9)
```

but the results I want like this:

```
Array([0] => 1,[1] => 2,[3] => 3,[4] => 4,[6] => 5,[9] => 6,[10] => 7,[14] => 8,[19] => 9)
```

This not only eliminates the value of the same array, but the same value that appears to be the value of the index / key of the last of the same value. anyone can help me?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You can simply use `array_unique($array)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get unique value from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290802/how-do-i-get-unique-value-from-an-array)

Comment: dude atleast try to google also there are many similar question has been asked in stackoverflow.

Comment: array_unique  is generating/eliminate the value of the same array, but I want to get the value of the index is the last..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've got the answer I want, thank you to all who have tried to help me.

```
$str = Array('0' => 1,'1' => 2,'2' => 3,'3' => 3,'4' => 4,'5' => 5,'6' => 5,'7' => 6,'8' => 6,'9' => 6,'10' => 7,'11' => 8,'12' => 8,'13' => 8,'14' => 8,'15' => 9,'16' => 9,'17' => 9,'18' => 9,'19' => 9);

$flag = 0;
foreach($str as $key=>$value)
{
   if($flag == $value)
   {
      unset($str[$key-1]);
   }
   $flag = $value;
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($str);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

Example:

```
array_unique($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array manipulation function

```
array_unique($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_unique()` function through you can get a unique value of array.

```
<?php

$data=Array(1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
$ans=array_unique($data);
print_r($ans);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_unique](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp)

```
<?php $arr=Array("[0]" => 1,"[1]" => 2,"[2]" => 3,"[3]" => 3,"[4]" => 4,"[5]" => 5,"[6]" => 5,"[7]" => 6,"[8]" => 6,"[9]" => 6,"[10]" => 7,"[11]" => 8,"[12]" => 8,"[13]" => 8,"[14]" => 8,"[15]" => 9,"[16]" => 9,"[17]" => 9,"[18]" => 9,"[19]" => 9);
var_dump($arr);
$newarr=array_unique($arr);
var_dump($newarr);
?>
```

Comment: yup..but the values that emerge from the first index. I want the value that appears on the index Last post of the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the build in array function.

```
array_unique();
```

give you the expected the results. Check the [link](http://php.net/array-unique)